# Suggestions for commands in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

Is there any auto-completion or suggestion available for commands in TeXworks?
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the TeXworks site, referring to [Using code completion](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/CodeCompletion):

> TeXworks comes with an expandable set of code templates that can
>   easily be inserted into a (La)TeX document. To insert a code template,
>   type the first few characters of the pattern name and press `<Tab>`. The
>   code template best matching the characters you typed will be inserted
>   and highlighted. If there are multiple code templates starting with
>   the characters you typed press `<Tab>` to cycle through the
>   possibilities.
>
> Some code templates include bullet characters `•`. These act as
>   placeholders where text should be inserted. Use `<Ctrl>+<Tab>` and
>   `<Shift>+<Ctrl>+<Tab>` (`<Alt>+<Tab>` and `<Alt>+<Shift>+<Tab>` on Mac) to
>   navigate between those placeholders.

For example, if you type `\begin{min` and press `<Tab>`, TeXworks will produce

```
\begin{minipage}{}
•
\end{minipage}•
```

You can navigate between the placeholders (the black dots) as described above.  Try typing `\te` and keep pressing `<Tab>` to see a list of several possibilities suggested.

You can also customize code completion; follow the link I provided and go down to the section **Customizing code completion**.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a hotkey expander, as it will save you a lot of time typing TeX code. I use three different products, depending on the operating system I'm on:

- Autohotkey under Windows
- Autokey under Linux
- TextExpander under Mac OS

The general procedure is always the same, one defines a hotkey, this hotkey is then expanded whenever it is printed.

Here are a few examples from Autohotkey which I use most of the time:

- if I type `s#` Autohotkey expands this to `\section{}` and places the cursor before the closing brace
- If I type `h-#` it gets expanded to the current date in ISO notation: 2014-02-07

I have compiled a list of useful hotkeys for an upcoming article in the German `Die TeXnische Komödie` under http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2875

Comment: A similar functionality provides in Windows [PhraseExpress: Autotext - Text Expander for Windows - Snippets Organizer](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) (free for personal use).